# How I can remove a item in my ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, listviewitem

I want do delete a entry in my asp.net ListView and it don't work with my code.

my code:

```
protected void ListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                int listcount = ListView.Items.Count;

                if (listcount - 1 == index)
                {
                    ListView.Items.RemoveAt(index); //go do ListView_Deleting 
                }

            }

        }

        protected void ListView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        protected void ListView_Deleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }
```

my aspx:

```
 <div class="InputControlBox">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView_ItemCommand"
            OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView_SelectedIndexChanging" OnItemDeleting="ListView_Deleting">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    ...
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                  ...
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
```

Where is the error?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Exception, just not deleting?

Comment: no exception...just no deleting :(

Comment: 'listcount - 1 == index' - doesnt this mean you can only delete the last item in the ListView?

Comment: yes i see it but this was not the error.... i have now the solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yor can use the code

```
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            int listcount = ListView.Items.Count;

            if (listcount - 1 == index)
            {
                dataTable.Rows[index].Delete();

                ListView.datasource = datatable;
                ListView.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

where dataTable is the datasource where you bind to your ListView.